# C++ fstream get function trap in a while loop

Tags: c++, get, fstream

Why is this function printing infinite points when reading from a text file?
The only solution I found was to re write the infile text and add an empty line.

```
void copyText(ifstream& intext, ofstream& outtext, char& ch, int list[]){        
    while (ch != '\n'){ 
        outtext << ch;
        intext.get(ch); 
    }
    outtext << ch; //writes the new line into the text. 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an infinite loop if `intext.get(ch);` fails (because of end of file maybe) and `ch` is not equal to `'\n'` (because the last character of the file is not a newline maybe). In that case `ch` will never change and it's not equal to `'\n'` so you have an infinite loop.

Here's how to write the loop correctly.

```
while (intext.get(ch) && ch != '\n') { 
    outtext << ch;
}
```

Now the while loop is testing for both read failure and end of line.

Answer (score 0):

If it runs in an infinite loop, it means there is no '\n' character in the file(This is the reason, you are able to stop the infinite loop by adding an empty line). if u r looking for an end of file check, change while loop check to ch != 0.